# Excel VBA, Check values from columns between sheets and delete duplicate

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I need some help with comparing values from one column to another and delating it.

so far I have this:

```
Sub DelateDuplicates()

delArray = Sheets("Save").Range("B1:B") ' saved values
toDelate = Sheets("Validation").Range("B2:B").Value ' values to be checked and delated
lastRow = toDelate.Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row ' last row
Firstrow = toDelate.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row ' First row

Dim i As Long

For Lrow = lastRow To Firstrow Step -1
    With Worksheets("Validation").Cells(Lrow, "A")
    For i = 0 To UBound(delArray)  ' arrays are indexed from zero
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = delArray(i) Then
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                    Exit For 
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next Lrow

End Sub
```

And I do have an error.
"1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" "

I have spent 2 days trying to figure it out so far no luck.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code little bit. You can define your first rows and last row the want you want, I have kept it simple for the sake of concept

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelateDuplicates()
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim delarray()
With Worksheets("Save")
delarray = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim firstrow As Long
firstrow = 1

With Worksheets("Validation")
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For Lrow = lastrow To firstrow Step -1
    For i = 1 To UBound(delarray)
            If Not IsError(.Cells(Lrow, "A").Value) Then
                If .Cells(Lrow, "A").Value = delarray(i, 1) Then
                    .Cells(Lrow, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
Next Lrow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great! This is exactly what I was trying to achive! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid loops within loops by using a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDuplicates()

    Dim wsSave As Worksheet, wsValid As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iFirstRow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim dict As Object, key, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSave = .Sheets("Save")
        Set wsValid = Sheets("Validation")
    End With
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' get values to delete from Column B
    For Each cell In wsSave.Range("B1", wsSave.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        key = Trim(cell)
        If Len(key) > 0 Then
            dict(key) = cell.Row
        End If
    Next

    ' scan Validation sheet and delete matching from Save
    With wsValid
        iFirstRow = .Cells(2, "B").End(xlDown).Row
        iLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = iLastRow To iFirstRow Step -1
            key = .Cells(i, "A")
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    ' resutl
    MsgBox n & " rows deleted between row " & _
            iFirstRow & " and " & iLastRow, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! However I am not familiar with Dictionary, it works but due to my needs to do with the data few other things, it will not be used at this time. I will definitely look into this as it looks useful. Thanks